# How define region/location for deploy Firestore 2nd gen functions written in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a Firestore  2nd gen functions with command `firebase deploy --only functions` but I got a error:

```
There was an issue deploying your functions. Verify that your project has a Google App Engine instance setup at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine and try again. If this issue persists, please contact support.
⚠  functions: Upload Error: HTTP Error: 400, Could not create bucket gcf-v2-uploads-758827227995-us-central1. 'us-central1' violates constraint 'constraints/gcp.resourceLocations'

Error: HTTP Error: 400, Could not create bucket gcf-v2-uploads-758827227995-us-central1. 'us-central1' violates constraint 'constraints/gcp.resourceLocations'
```

According to a [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#best_practices_for_changing_region), use just:

```
exports.myStorageFunction = functions
    .region('europe-west1')
    .storage
    .object()
    .onFinalize((object) => {
      // ...
    });
```

How I can do in Python? my function was written in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=2nd#keep_a_minimum_number_of_instances_warm) as reference, you can define runtime options in the arguments of functions decorator. If you’re trying to set the region for a Firebase Cloud Function written in Python, you can try specifying the region in the functions decorator like so:

```py
from firebase_functions import https_fn

@https_fn.on_request(region='asia-east1')
# @https_fn.on_request()
def on_request_example(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    return https_fn.Response("Hello world!")
```

If you’re configuring a Cloud Firestore trigger(e.g. `on_document_created`), it would look like:

```py
from firebase_functions.firestore_fn import (
    on_document_created,
    Event,
    DocumentSnapshot,
)


@on_document_created(document="users/{userId}", region="asia-east1")
def userCreated(event: Event[DocumentSnapshot]) -> None:
    new_value = event.data.to_dict()
    name = new_value["name"]
    print(name)
```

Comment: It works to me!

Answer (score 0):

**use the region property in the firebase.functions.config()**

```
import firebase

firebase_admin = firebase.initialize_app()

functions = firebase_admin.functions

config = functions.config()

config.region = "us-central1"
```

**This will deploy your function to the us-central1 region. You can also use the location property to deploy your function to a specific location within a region**

```
config.location = "us-central1-a"
```

- This will deploy your function to the us-central1-a location.
- The default region for Firestore 2nd gen functions is us-central1. If
  you do not specify a region, your function will be deployed to this
  region.

Comment: I had tried this, but config is not a method.